# How to set repeated field to repeate at least one time in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I've started to use Google's `protobuf` and there is repeated field type:

```
repeated: this field can be repeated any number of times (including zero)
in a well-formed message. The order of the repeated values will be preserved.
```

What I need to know is how to make a message with a repeated field that repeats at least once. So I need to exclude zero times in this type somehow. I can do such an assertion in my code, but what is the proper way to do this inside .proto file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't want to do that with protobufs. It's much better to assert in the code. The big reason is that once you have such a requirement (ex. required fields), you end up in a situation where you can never loosen the requirement. You may have old binaries running that suddenly start failing to read your newly constructed protobufs because they don't meet the requirements. And if you add a required field, you hit a situation where old data that you need to replay with current binaries will have failures due to not having the bits set.

Given that it's a serialization format, it's really best to separate the application logic (validation of values, etc) from the serialization logic. The format doesn't offer an "at least one" repeated field enforced on the serialization layer.

If you absolutely must fake it, you could have a required foo, and then a repeated extra_foos, but your logic would be harder to write.